# Slim 3 - Flash message not showing up after redirecting

Tags: php, slim

I have this problem with slim flash when I create `remember me` functionality. Here is my route

```
/* authenticated */
$app->group('', function () {
  $this->get('/', 'HomeController:index')->setName('home');
})->add(new \App\Middleware\HomeMiddleware($container));

/* public */
$app->->group('', function () {
  $this->get('/login', 'AuthController:getLogin')->setName('get.login');
  $this->post('/login', 'AuthController:postLogin');
})->add(new \App\Middleware\PublicMiddleware($container));
```

In my `HomeMiddleware`

```
Class HomeMiddleware extends Middleware
{
  public function __invoke($request, $response, $next)
  {
    if (!Session::exists('u_session') && !Cookie::exists('user')) {
      return $response->withRedirect($this->router->pathFor('get.login'));
    }

    if (!Session::exists('u_session') && Cookie::exists('user')) {
      $hash = Cookie::get('user');

      $ucookie = new UCookie;
      $check = $ucookie->where('hash', $hash)->first();

      if (!$check) {
        Cookie::delete('user');
        return $response->withRedirect($this->router->pathFor('get.login'));
      }

      $newhash = bin2hex(random_bytes(32));

      Cookie::set('user', $newhash);

      $ucookie->hash = $newhash;
      $ucookie->save();

      Session::set('u_session', $ucookie->user_id);

      $this->flash->addMessage('success', 'Welcome back!');
      return $response->withRedirect($this->router->pathFor('home'));
    }

    return $next($request, $response);
  }
}
```

and here is my `PublicMiddleware`

```
class PublicMiddleware extends Middleware
{
  public function __invoke($request, $response, $next)
  {
    if (Session::exists('u_session') || Cookie::exists('user')) {
      return $response->withRedirect($this->router->pathFor('home'));
    }

    return $next($request, $response);
  }
}
```

1. Delete PHPSESSID and try to access home page or login page, the flash message show up as it is. Good
2. Try to access login page without deleting PHPSESSID. It redirects to home page. Good
3. After number 2, I delete PHPSESSID then try to access my login page again then the flash message didnt show up as it should be.

I don't know why after number (3) flash message just show up when I try to access home page (after deleting PHPSESSID) but it doesn't when I try to access login page.

Comment: Do you start the session on every page?

Comment: Well ofc. It's on my initialization file which contain all config.

Comment: Okay, it's not obvious since I don't know what the initialization looks like file :) When you say you delete your session, what does it mean in terms of code? Since Slim Flash uses sessions to store messages.

Comment: edited. I mean PHPSESSID which store my login session, CMIIW.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. I got this problem a few months back, and while I don't know how you fetch the messages, my solution was to use `addMessageNow`. At least that helped me to identify where the error was since `addMessageNow` adds the message for access before any redirect.

Comment: I have tried that before and the result is same. If I'm not mistaken, addMessageNow is adding message for the current request, not for the next request. Why addMessageNow if I'm redirecting to another page which is another request CMIIW? The problem occured when I try to access login page (after PHPSESSID deleted), the flash message not show up.

Comment: Yes, that's the purpose of `addMessageNow`. Like I said, I had the same problem which was caused how I fetched the stored messages and passed them to the template, hence it's better to eliminate the possibility of "simpler" errors before digging down deeper into the problem. Good luck though, hope you find a solution.

Comment: For point 3, add a log message immediately after the flash message call in HomeMiddleware, so we can prove that the code to add the flash message is being called.

Comment: @RobAllen I add `dd($this->flash->getMessage('success'))` but somehow its skipped and `PHPSESSID` was restored eventhough I've deleted it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured it out with simple solution but not sure if its good enough. I simply redirect to another `authenticated route` and handle the flashing from it

```
Class HomeMiddleware extends Middleware
{
  public function __invoke($request, $response, $next)
  {
    if (!Session::exists('u_session') && !Cookie::exists('user')) {
      return $response->withRedirect($this->router->pathFor('get.login'));
    }

    if (!Session::exists('u_session') && Cookie::exists('user')) {

      $data = explode('_', Cookie::get('user'));

      if (!empty($data) && count($data) === 2) {
        $token = $data[0];
        $hash = $data[1];

        $ucookie = UCookie::where('token', $token)->first();

        if (!$ucookie || !password_verify($hash, $ucookie->hash)) {
          Cookie::delete('user');
          return $response->withRedirect($this->router->pathFor('get.login'));
        }

        $newtoken = bin2hex(random_bytes(32));
        $newhash = bin2hex(random_bytes(32));

        $ucookie->token = $newtoken;
        $ucookie->hash = password_hash($newhash, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
        $ucookie->save();

        Cookie::set('user', $newtoken . '_' . $newhash);
        Session::set('u_session', $ucookie->user_id);

        return $response->withRedirect($this->router->pathFor('flash.success'));
      }
    }

    return $next($request, $response);
  }
}
```

And create new authenticated route which is accessible because I have create a session login

```
$app->group('', function () {

  $this->get('/flash-success', 'FlashController:flashSuccess')->setName('flash.success');

})->add(new \App\Middleware\HomeMiddleware($container));
```

And inside my `FlashController` just add new method

```
class FlashController extends Controller
{
  public function flashSuccess($request, $response)
  {
    $this->flash->addMessage('success', 'Welcome back!');
    return $response->withRedirect($this->router->pathFor('home'));
  }
}
```

With this, flash message always show up.